# GTA V iFruit app

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-ifruit

I have GTA V and I just downloaded the iFruit app. What I'm wondering is will I have to be playing online for the Los Angeles customs to work or even the chop feature? Or will they work even while playing single player offline?

Answer (score 2):

They should only work offline, but you can have your mechanic deliver cars for you. There is no chop online because you are not franklin.